# Уточнение корней методом хорд в Delphi 7

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, delphi-7

Уточните корень уравнения е^х – 10х = 0 на отрезке [a, b] методом хорд.

```
  program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function f(x,eps:real):real;
begin
f:=exp(x*ln(eps))-10*x;
end;
var a,b,c,x,eps:real;
begin
writeln('vvedite a & b');
Readln (a,b);
writeLn('vvedite tochnost eps');
readln(eps);
repeat
   c := (f(b, eps) * a - f(a, eps) * b) / (f(b, eps) - f(a, eps));
   if f(a, eps)*f(c, eps) > 0 then a := c
   else b := c;
 until (f(b, eps)*a-f(a, eps)*b)/(f(b, eps)-f(a, eps))-c)<eps;
   x:=c
 writeLn('koren x=', x:10:7);
 Readln;
end.
```

на 18 строчке(присваивание формулы для вывода X выдается ошибка Not enough actual parameters)
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У функции `f` - два параметра.

```
x := (f(b, eps) * a - f(a, eps) * b) / (f(b, eps) - f(a, eps));
```

---

Следующие вопросы:

- откуда взялась переменная `c`?
- откуда берутся значения переменных `a` и `b`?

---

> Type of expression must be BOOLEAN на 22 строке,

Не хватает одной круглой скобки.

```
until ((f(b, eps)*a-f(a, eps)*b)/(f(b, eps)-f(a, eps))-c)<eps;
      ^
```

Comment: c- формула для вычислений, в Var уже добавил,а и b- границы, вводятся пользователем

Comment: Исправил, но теперь выходит другая:
Type of expression must be BOOLEAN на 22 строке, код обновил